# Split log data by MB size in Python

Tags: python

There is a process that generates log data of size more than 10 mb. I have been instructed to split the data into 10mb chunks maximum and write to text files means if the log size is 25 mb then it should be divided into 3 parts - 10, 10, 5mb and written to 3 text files.
Also the second and third text file names should be like "file..._1", "file..._2". To write the _1 and _2, I am using the code - `filename="file" + "_" + np.arange(1, 10, 1) + ".txt"` but when it is creating a new file with underscore, it is giving UFuncTypeError.

My code is:

```py
def writelog(self, filename, msgstr):
    #writing log to .txt file
    filename = "log-" + str(date.today()) + ".txt"
    current_date_and_time = str(datetime.now())
    logfile = open(filename, 'a')
    logfile.write(current_date_and_time + msgstr)
    logfile.close()

    #checking if the text file is more than 10mb, then create a new file
    filelocation = "...location.../log-2021-07-20.txt"
    filesize = os.stat(filelocation)
    sizeoflog = filesize.st_size / (1024 * 1024)
    print('Size of log in MB- ' + str(sizeoflog))
    
    if sizeoflog > 10:
        filename = "log-" + str(date.today()) + "_" + np.arange(1, 10, 1) + ".txt"
        logfile = open(filename, 'a')
        logfile.write(current_date_and_time + msgstr)
        logfile.close()
    
    return filename
```

`msgstr` is a dictionary that I passed in main.py

So, the summary is:

1. split the data into 10mb chunks each and write to file
2. first file name will be like `log-today's date.txt`, second file name will be `log-today's date_1.txt` and so on.
3. each file content should start with `current_date_and_time` and then the `msgstr`.

How can I address these problems ? I am a beginner in Python..

Comment: What do you think adding a np.array to a string would do?

Comment: It should print the whole array, but I am getting same UFuncTypeError for np.array((1 to 10))

Comment: Hi, it seems that you are a python beginner. Please post your full code, if you need help - or a reproducable example. For your question - it seems you want to create a list of differint file names and not a single file name that combines all, so even if adding np.arrange to a strng would work, you would not get a usable result. Also, python has it's own `range` function, if you just want to count to 10.

Comment: you are adding an array to a string, that does not work. `np.arange(1, 10, 1)` gives you an array type. Share more code.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach. I created 2 simple helper functions, one for the filesize (with a `try: except` block) and another to find the last logfile with a size under 10MB.

Since they don't care about the class itself, you should use the `@staticmethod` [decorator](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/#static-methods). Note that you need to change the method calls to both `getsize()` and `find_current_log()` as I don't know the class name.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import os

class ClassNameGoesHere:
    @staticmethod
    def getsize(filename):
        try: 
            return os.stat(filename).st_size / 1048576
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return 0

    @staticmethod
    def find_current_log(filename):
        base_filename = os.path.basename(filename)
        if '_' in base_filename:
            counter = int(base_filename.split('_')[1].split('.')[0])
        else:
            counter = 0
        while ClassNameGoesHere.getsize(filename) >= 10:
            counter += 1
            if '_' in base_filename:
                base_filename = f"{base_filename.split('_')[0]}_{counter}.txt"
            else:
                base_filename = f"{base_filename.split('.')[0]}_{counter}.txt"
            filename = f'{os.path.dirname(filename)}{os.sep}{base_filename}'
        return filename 

    def writelog(self, filename, msgstr):
        filename = ClassNameGoesHere.find_current_log(filename)
        with open(filename, 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(f'{datetime.now()} | {msgstr}\n')

somelogger = ClassNameGoesHere()
somelogger.writelog('path/to/file/log-2021-07-21.txt', 'this is a test messsage')
```

Comment: Hi Edo, this served the purpose, thanks a lot